# Are servers allowed to add a Content-Encoding header based on filename, if there is no compression on-the-fly?

Tags: http-headers, compression, gzip, encoding

### Problem

Suppose we have a compressed archive on disk, e.g. `file.tar.gz`, which should be served as-is.

The file is served with `Content-Type: application/gzip`, but for some reason the server also adds a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header, even though it does *not* apply any additional on-the-fly compression (so *no* `mod_deflate` or similar).

As a result, some user-agents (e.g. Python's [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) and `urllib3`) will automatically decompress the gzip file, so, after download, we end up with `file.tar`, instead of `file.tar.gz`.

### Examples

One example is the Django development server, which adds a `Content-Encoding` header based on the filename, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/70147215bb848539273b42617b32773013bcdc47/django/views/static.py#L47).

Another example is `django-storages` in combination with AWS S3. If a gzip file is uploaded to an S3 bucket using `django-storages` (v1.12.3), a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header is added to the file metadata, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/7dd36fb820b796ec02bcd35be19e32617f55c7d3/storages/backends/s3boto3.py#L503). When downloading that file from S3, the `Content-Encoding` from the metadata is added to the download response headers.

### Question

Is this acceptable server behavior, or should the server be considered *broken*?

### What I found

This excerpt from [rfc7231](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#header.content-encoding) appears to suggest the behavior is *not* acceptable:

> ... Content-Encoding is primarily used to allow a representation's data to be compressed without losing the identity of its underlying media type.
> ...
> If the media type includes an inherent encoding, such as a data format that is always compressed, then that encoding would not be restated in Content-Encoding ...

although "primarily" implies there may be alternative uses.

Here's the same thing, in slightly different words, from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding):

> ... If the original media is encoded in some way (e.g. a zip file) then this information would not be included in the `Content-Encoding` header.

However, [rfc7231](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#header.content-encoding) then goes on to say the following, which (I think) suggests the behavior *can* be acceptable:

> ... Likewise, an origin server might choose to publish the same data as multiple representations that differ only in whether the coding is defined as part of `Content-Type` or `Content-Encoding`, since some user agents will behave differently in their handling of each response (e.g., open a "Save as ..." dialog instead of automatic decompression and rendering of content).

If this *is* acceptable server behavior, then I suppose our user-agent would need to take that into account.

Comment: See also [ngx_http_gzip_static_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html#gzip_static). Seems reasonable to mimic such logic in the dev server, given there is zero intersection between *compression encodings* and *Django static file types*.